# Cannot read property 'toastr' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, undefined, toastr

I have been trying to implement express-toastr into my express js form and use it to send the express-validator error messages as toast notifications, however when I place the required `div #{req.toastr.render()}` inside my index.pug file I receive the error `Cannot read property 'toastr' of undefined` when attempting to load the page.

Full error:

```
        TypeError: /home/bob/project/views/index.pug:34
    32|         h1(class="section__title") Title1
    33|         div(class="centerBlock") 
> 34|           div #{req.toastr.render()}
    35|             .col-xs-12
    36|               form(action='', method='post', id='form')
    37|                 .row

Cannot read property 'toastr' of undefined
    at eval (eval at wrap (/home/bob/project/node_modules/pug-runtime/wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:117:61)
    at template (eval at wrap (/home/bob/project/node_modules/pug-runtime/wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:245:131)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/bob/project/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:428:38)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/bob/project/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:418:21)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (/home/bob/project/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:465:11)
    at View.render (/home/bob/project/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/home/bob/project/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/home/bob/project/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/bob/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at /home/bob/project/routes/index.js:19:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/bob/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/bob/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/bob/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/bob/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/bob/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/bob/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

My layout.pug is as follows:

```
link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/toastr.css")
script(src="/js/jquery.js")
script(src="/js/toastr.js")
```

and my app.js:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var toastr = require('express-toastr');

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(toastr());

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + 
'/node_modules/jquery/dist')); // redirect JS jQuery + toastr.js is in this folder
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + 
'/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')); // redirect CSS bootstrap;
```

index.js:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('index', { title: 'Project' });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res){

var errors = req.getValidationResult();

if (errors){
    for (error in errors){
      req.toastr.error(error.msg)
    }
    res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
    return;
  }
})
```

I am relatively new to nodejs but I have been managing thus far, however I have tried and tried and cannot figure out why this will not work. Apologies if I am missing something extremely simple.

Cheers,
Kyle.

Comment: Do you have a directory setup to server your static files? CSS, JS, images, etc. https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: yes, I just didn't include it in the app.js snapshot to save space. i'll update the question.

Comment: Where are you passing a `req` into your view?

Comment: sorry, where would one do that?

Comment: Does there is all code in **index.js**? I guess there must be another route likes **req.get('/')** and will call the **res.render** method and pass into the **req** object as parameter.

Comment: @KevinLaw I have updated the post to include the router.get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you don't pass the **req** object to view render function.
Change your **get** method of **index.js** to following:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { 
        title: 'Project',
        req: req });
});
```

More usage document could be found [here](https://github.com/kamaln7/express-toastr).

Comment: I have changed this and the error still persists. The whole site fails to load once I add `div #{req.toastr.render()}` to the templating file

Comment: ignore that last comment, I made a typo :P, it is now loading fine. Thank you!